# %s not working properly with my return value, in C

Tags: c

As the title says %s is not working properly This is for a code wars so %s needs to be able to work with the array to pass the sample test cases; Cannot change function declaration  of playPass. Using Ascii table.  Also the for loop to print in main() works and gives me correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// takes a string and shifts letter n value;
// lower cases every other element if it contains a letter
// replaces number with a 9 complement 
// returns array with values reversed.
char* playPass(char* s, int n) 
{
    int length = strlen(s); 
    char *pass= (char *)malloc(length*sizeof(char)+1); 
    char a; 
    int letter, i; 


    for(i=0; i< length; i++) 
    {
        a = s[i];
        letter = a;

        if( letter >= 65 && letter <=90  )
        {

             letter +=n; 

            if(letter >90)
            { 
                letter -=90; 
                letter +=64; 
            } 
            if((i+1) % 2 == 0  )
            {
                letter += 32;

            }

            a = letter; 

       }
        else if(letter >= 48 &&  letter <= 57)
        {
            letter -= 48;
            letter = 9 - letter; 
            a = letter + '0'; 
        }

        pass[length - i] = a;  
   }

  return pass;   
}
// answer should be 
int main (){

    char* s ={"I LOVE YOU!!!"}; 
    int length = strlen(s);
    int k = 1; 
    s =playPass( s,k ); 
    int i; 
    printf(" %s", s);
    for(i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    { 
        printf(" %c", s[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: **never use magic numbers** like `letter >= 65 && letter <= 90`. Isn't `letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z'` more readable? And not all systems use ASCII so the values may be different (although for practical purposes nowadays most use ASCII)

Comment: `malloc()` does not zero-initialise the memory it allocates, your `playPass()` function does not give the string a nul (zero) terminator, and `%s` format gives undefined behaviour if no nul terminator is present.

Answer (score 4):

`%s` works only with null terminated `char *`

```
char* playPass(char* s, int n) {

    …
    for() {
       …
    }
    pass[i] = '\0'; //Null terminate here.
    return pass;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply after i fixed the main problem of the null at the 0th element this was definitely the next fix.

Answer (score 0):

so figured it out.

the end where i assined the new value to the new array

```
 pass[length - i] = a;
```

made it to where it never wrote a value to the first element so

```
pass[0]= NULL;
```

had to change it to

```
pass[length - (i-1)] = a;
```

thanks for the help everyone, I also cleaned up the code from the magic numbers Great tip @phuclv!